# Swift mongoc.h file not found

Tags: swift, mongodb, macos

I am trying to install the [Mongo Swift](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-swift-driver) library using cocoapods but am fronting some problems.

As the documentation pointed out, for the mongo swift pod to work, it needs the mongo-c-driver. Which I installed using homebrew and is sitting in the Cellar folder in my usr folder(Meaning it is installed). I then modified the podfile the same as the example and when running `pod install` the library is correctly installed.

The problem then comes when i open the project and try to build it. I have now these two errors:

> 'mongoc.h' file not found
>
> Could not build Objective-C module 'libmongoc'

I made sure that I open the xcworkspace and not the default workspace.
I also tried to add the path to the mongoc.h file to the Runpath Search Path in hope of some results but without luck.

As you may see i do not understand a lot of this and it basically could be something silly. But I do not know how to get this library to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to get it to work.

I don't know why this happened but the header and library search paths were set wrongfully. I had installed version 1.10 of the mongo-c-driver and the search version in xCode was set to 1.94.

I also was trying to modify the search paths in my own project rather in the cocoa project which led to absolutely no results.

TLDR; Add the correct include and lib folder to the Header/Library Search Path in Xcode and make sure you set it in the Pods Project.